# Magento: Configurable product options not showing on a view page?

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I have multi-store Magento system and strange things happen when i try to see a configurable product on my main store - the options select lists don't show up at all! And that is the case for the 95% of the products on the main store.

But on the other stores it works fine?!

I can't see what am I doing wrong. All my products are configurable, all have set simple products with options attached to them, all are set to be visible on all stores (WebsiteIds attribute), all are enabled on all stores, all simple products are in stock and have some stock quantity set.

I think if I've done something wrong it would be like that on all stores, not just the main one. I'm totally clueless, please help. I've attached couple of images to see the difference.

http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/3224/59155765.jpg
http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/8145/98963713.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing cache and rebuilding indexes? I would rebuild all indexes related to products (Product Attributes, Product Flat Data, Stock Status, etc).

Comment: Tried that, doesn't help. I am refreshing indexes all the time, and cache is disabled while project is in develpment.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe something goes wrong with your template. Please check this file:

app/design/frontend/**your_theme**/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml.

The following code is existed or not?

**var spConfig = new Product.Config(getJsonConfig() ?>);**

Or check carefully your javascript in console debug of Chrome.

Good luck :)

Comment: Things do take ages in Magento but I really hope this dude isn't still debugging his problem over 6 years later. The client will have a heart attack when they get the bill ;)

Comment: Haha, I hope so. Maybe it will be useful for another person.

Comment: Thank you for the notice, @McNab :)